# How do you find the roots of the negative polynomial $(-x^3 - x + 1)$ to further use for partial fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to factor the polynomial $p(x)=-x^3-x+1$ to use in partial fractions, but I am getting stumped on how to break this up into roots. Any tips will be helpful!  My teacher did something similar incorporating alpha and beta, and the quadratic formula, but I didn’t follow.

Comment: How that? No polynomial of degree $>2$ is irreducible over $\mathbf R$.

Comment: how is this polynomial negative?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$? How are there $2$ roots?

Comment: The fact that the leading term has a minus sign is irrelevant when looking for the partial fraction decomposition. The polynomial has one real and two (conjugate) complex roots, so decomposes into a linear and an irreducible quadratic factor. The roots aren't pretty (check on Wolfram alpha  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+++-x%5E3+-x++%2B1+%3D+0).

Comment: Partial fractions? Don't they cover that in calculus? (-1 for putting `algebra-precalculus` tag)

Comment: @Bernard interestingly, wolfram alpha thinks it is irreducible, well, I see they mean over Q.

Comment: Her example stated that g(x)= 1-x-x^2 = 1-alphax and 1-betax, where alpha and beta are roots of x^2 + x + 1, and x^2 * g(1/x).  She called the values of alpha and beta the golden mean.

Comment: The real root is $x=\frac2{\sqrt3}\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)\right)$

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you, I believe what you stated is the path I need.  I’ll have to look up how to do this.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus [Well-known sustitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions)

Comment: Is it $1-x-x^2$ or $1-x-x^3$? Also if there is something more to this problem perhaps you don't need to factor $-x^3-x+1$

Comment: @user5713492 So you just looked it up on Wikipedia and subed in ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus No, I searched for the reference after you asked. Isn't that how everyone solve a cubic?

Comment: @user5713492 Well, no, I know such formulas existed but I havnt memorized them. Are they of much practical use ?

Comment: @YoloInver  I've seen high school algebra curriculums that teach partial fractions.  If you add rational expressions, it makes sense to un-add them.  It's only incidentally a calculus topic.

Answer (score 1):

Cubic equations in the form $x^3+px+q=0$ can be solved by the substitution $x=rf(\theta)$ so
$$r^3\left[f(\theta)\right]^3+rf(\theta)p+q=0$$
Then multiply by $4/r^3$ to get
$$4\left[f(\theta)\right]^3+\frac{4p}{r^2}f=\frac{-4q}{r^3}$$
Choose the sign of $r=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4|p|}3}$ such that $qr\le0$. Then
$$4\left[f(\theta)\right]^3+3\frac{p}{|p|}f(\theta)=\left|\frac{4q}{r^3}\right|$$
Match with one of
$$\begin{align}\cos(3\theta)&=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta\\
\cosh(3\theta)&=4\cosh^3\theta-3\cosh\theta\\
\sinh(3\theta)&=4\sinh^3\theta+3\sinh\theta\end{align}$$
In our case, $p=1$, $q=-1$, $r=\frac2{\sqrt3}$ and
$$\sinh(3\theta)=4\sinh^3\theta+3\sinh\theta=\frac{3\sqrt3}2$$
So
$$\theta=\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)$$
And our solution is
$$a=\frac2{\sqrt3}\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)\right)$$
Then we can do partial fractions:
$$\begin{align}\frac1{x^3+x-1}&=\frac1{\left(x^2+ax+a^2+1\right)(x-a)}\\
&=\frac1{31}\left[\frac{-\left(6a^2+9a+4\right)x-\left(18a^2-4a+12\right)}{x^2+ax+a^2+1}+\frac{6a^2+9a+4}{x-a}\right]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The potential rational zeroes of the polynomial $x^3+x-1$ are $\pm1.$ Unfortunately none of them provides a true zero of this polynomial. However since this is a cubic polynomial, there must be at least one real zero. According to Descartes's sign rule, it has exactly one real zero and it is positive. In fact, one can use Tartaglia-Cardeno method to find this zero exactly.

Let that zero be $\alpha.$ Then we can factor the given polynomial as $x^3+x-1=(x-\alpha)(x^2+px+q),$ where the (second) quadratic factor is irreducible in to linear factors with real numbers. By equating coefficients of above equality, one can easily find both $p, q$ in-terms of $\alpha.$ Then using quadratic formula, we can find the complete factorization of the original cubic polynomial over complex numbers.

Now if you need the (real valued) partial fraction decomposition of $$\dfrac{1}{x^3+x-1},$$ we can write it as $$\dfrac{A}{x-\alpha}+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+px+q}$$ and further we can find $A, B, C$ in-terms of $\alpha.$